# selenium-server won't `setValue`

Tags: selenium, webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm using `selenium-server` version 3.0.1 and `nightwatch` version ^0.9.12 on node 8.9.0. My e2e test do run, clicks work, and reading the DOM works, but `setValue` just doesn't.

For example, the following test:

```
browser
  .url("...")

  .waitForElementPresent('select[name=foo]', 5000)
  .click('select[name=foo] option:nth-child(2)')

  .waitForElementPresent('input[name=bar]', 5000)
  .setValue('input[name=bar]', "hello world")
  .getValue('input[name=bar]', function(input) {
    this.assert.equal(input.value, "hello world");
  })

  .end();
```

will open the url, wait for `foo` and click the second option. It will wait for `bar`, then fails:

```
Running: test
 ✔ Element <select[name=foo]> was present after 24 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <input[name=bar]> was present after 28 milliseconds.
 ✖ Failed [equal]: ('' == 'hello world')  - expected "hello world" but got: ""
    at Object.<anonymous> (/test/e2e/specs/test.js:49:21)


FAILED:  1 assertions failed and 2 passed (4.692s)

 _________________________________________________

 TEST FAILURE:  1 assertions failed, 2 passed. (4.9s)

 ✖ test

   - run through apply process (4.692s)
   Failed [equal]: ('' == 'hello world')  - expected "hello world" but got: ""
```

If I replace the `setValue` with a delay and enter a value by hand, the test will pass, so `getValue` is working.

This does run, and pass, on other systems, but I can't get it working on my own so I think it's a `selenium-server` issue.

I've tried a lot of the 101 fixes, clearing the npm cache, re-running an `npm install`, etc. But with no errors other than the failure, how do I debug this?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Chrome 65?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to test using Chrome, you need to update your ChromeDriver.
Chrome 65 was released recently and older ChromeDriver versions are apparently incompatible with it.

Download the latest one from the [downloads](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) page.

Make Nightwatch use it, `nightwatch.json` -

```
{
...
    "selenium": {
...
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "path/to/chromedriver.exe"
```

Assuming Nightwatch uses it (you can see which one it uses using the Windows Task Manager - assuming you are using Windows - look for the command line of chromedriver.exe), `setValue` should now work again.

Comment: That did it! I had chromedriver installed through the npm package. Ran an update on that and now it's working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
Failed [equal]: ('' == 'hello world')  - expected "hello world" but got: ""
```

In your code block you have induced `wait` for the *WebElement* identified as **'input[name=bar]'** and next  invoked `setValue()` which is successful as follows :

```
.waitForElementPresent('input[name=bar]', 5000)
.setValue('input[name=bar]', "hello world")
```

Now the *JavaScript* associated with this *WebElement* identified as **'input[name=bar]'** will require some time to render the value within the *HTML DOM*. But in you code block you are trying to access the entered value (in the previous step) too early. Hence your script finds `<null>` as the *value*.

### Solution

You need to induce a *waiter* i.e. [expect](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#expect-text) clause for the value to be rendered within the *HTML DOM* through the associated *JavaScript* as follows :

```
.waitForElementPresent('input[name=bar]', 5000)
.setValue('input[name=bar]', "hello world")
.expect.element('input[name=bar]').to.have.value.that.equals('hello world');
.getValue('input[name=bar]', function(input) {
  this.assert.equal(input.value, "hello world");
})
```

Comment: I believe Nightwatch continues to the next command only after the current command finishes, so setValue waits until it finished "typing". Otherwise, setValue(...); setValue(...) would type in two fields in parallel, right? Which does not happen.

Comment: @PhistucK I think we are on the similar lines. Of-coarse `finished "typing"` necessarily doesn't implies that the associated JS have completed rendering the text within the _HTML DOM_

Comment: I think it does, actually. It is just that I updated to Chrome 65 (and updated my ChromeDriver as well) and I am having a similar issue - `waitForElementVisible(...); setValue(...); waitForElementVisible(...); setValue(...);` - the field is focused, but the text is not entered at all (I am not using Headless, so I can clearly see that), the the second field is focused, but the text is, again, not entered at all. It worked until Chrome 65. The asker did not mention that they use Chrome 65, but I have a hunch that they do.